# Удаление конкретного элемента по индексу

Tags: python

```
def func(number):
    number_list = []
    for i in number:
        number_list.append(i)
        if number_list[2] == '(' and number_list[6] == ')':
            del number_list[2]
            del number_list[6]
    print(number_list)
a = input('Введите номер:')
print(func(a))
```

Суть задачи, чтобы из вводимого номера телефона удалить скобки. Допустим ввожу: `+7(928)4567809`. На выходе хочу получить тот же номер, но без скобок

Ошибка на выходе, которую не понимаю как исправить:

```
  if '(' in number_list[-11] and ')' in number_list[-7]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: После удаления элемента с индексом 2 элемент, который раньше имел индекс 6, теперь будет иметь индекс 5 ;)

Comment: Попробуйте удалять символы справа налево - это позволит избежать подобных проблем

Comment: Проблема в if  ошибка: list index out of range

Comment: Вы можете более широко описать задачу? Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Попробуйте привести в вопросе небольшой воспроизводимый пример входных данных и итоговый результат, который вы хотите получить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Условие `if` вы ставите в цикл, на первой итерации которого `number_list` вообще не имеет элементов, а вы пытаетесь обратиться к элементу под индексом 2 - ошибка.
2. Если вы условие `if` поместите после цикла, то вы удалите не вторую скобку, а идущую за ней цифру из-за смещения индексов.
3. Вы пытаетесь вывести результат `func`, но в самой функции вы ничего не возвращаете.

Предлагаемый мною вариант корректировки:

```
def func(number):
    number_list = []
    for i in number:
        number_list.append(i)
    offset = 0
    if number_list[2 + offset] == '(':
        del number_list[2 + offset]
        offset -= 1
    if number_list[6 + offset] == ')':
        del number_list[6 + offset]
        offset -= 1
    print(number_list)
    return ''.join(number_list)
a = "+7(928)4567809"#input('Введите номер:')
print(func(a))
```

Альтернатива:

```
def func(phoneno: str):
    result = str()
    for char in phoneno:
        if char.isdigit() or char == "+":
            result += char
    return result
a = "+7(928)4567809"#input('Введите номер:')
print(func(a))
```

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = number.replace("(", "").replace(")", "")
```

Но более гибко будет воспользоваться регулярным выражением, чтобы удалить любые символы кроме цифр и знака `+`:

```
import re

res = re.sub(r"[^\d+]", "", number)
```

Пример:

```
In [6]: number = "+7(928) 456 / 78 - 09"

In [7]: re.sub(r"[^\d+]", "", number)
Out[7]: '+79284567809'
```